# Compiler fails to recognize a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

This is a very stripped-down version of some code I have that fails to compile.

```
template <typename name_of_type_t> class classA_t
{ /* etc etc etc */ };

template <typename name_of_type_t> class classB_t 
{
    public:
        classA_t<name_of_type_t> && return_new();
};

classA_t<name_of_type_t> && classB_t::return_new() // <-- errors here
{
    classA_t<name_of_type_t> * S = new classA_t<name_of_type_t>;
    return std::move(*S);
}

int main() { return 0; }
```

The compiler error I get is

```
template_error.cpp:12:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'name_of_type_t'
classA_t<name_of_type_t> && classB_t::return_new()
         ^
template_error.cpp:12:29: error: 'classB_t' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
classA_t<name_of_type_t> && classB_t::return_new()
                            ^
template_error.cpp:4:42: note: 'classB_t' declared here
template <typename name_of_type_t> class classB_t 
                                         ^
2 errors generated.
```

If `name_of_type_t` is undeclared, why didn't the compiler flag my earlier uses of it?  What does the compiler think `classB_t` is, if not a class?

Comment: On a side note: what is the point of `new`'ing an object, but then dereferencing the pointer and returning an rvalue reference to the object? That is a memory leak waiting to happen. Why not just return the object by value instead? `classA_t<name_of_type_t> return_new() { return classA_t<name_of_type_t>(); }` Or, at least return it as a `std::unique_ptr` instead: `unique_ptr<classA_t<name_of_type_t>> return_new() { return make_unique<classA_t<name_of_type_t>>(); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau There's no point to that. One of the compiler errors does reference the `classA_t<name_of_type_t> &&` return type, so I wanted to preserve it just in case it was relevant.  As I mentioned, this is stripped-down code.  In the original there was a lot more code in that function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classB_t` is a template.  When declaring its member function out of the class definition, you need to declare the template parameter list again, and specify the template parameters in the class type, e.g.

```
template <typename name_of_type_t>
classA_t<name_of_type_t> && classB_t<name_of_type_t>::return_new()
{
    classA_t<name_of_type_t> * S = new classA_t<name_of_type_t>;
    return std::move(*S);
}
```